# Failed to unwrap key exception android O on Diffie-Hellman encryption

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-keystore, diffie-hellman

I am using Diffie-Hellman encryption and decryption algorithm for my app username and password.I am using my keystore to store information and retrieving It is working properly working in below android O.Recently i am facing this issue please help me

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to unwrap key
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to unwrap key\n
Caused by: com.sample.example.sdk.manager.utils.CustomException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to unwrap key\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.KeyPairHelper.getDevicePrivatekKey(KeyPairHelper.java:60)\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.SampleTask.buildAesKey(SampleTask.java:100)\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.SampleTask.call(SampleTask.java:186)\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.SampleTask.call(SampleTask.java:66)\n\tat 
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:42)\n\tat 
io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)\n\tat 
io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)\n\tat 
io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)\n\tat io.reactivex.internal.
schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)\n\tat 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)\n
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Failed to unwrap key\n\tat 
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineUnwrap(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:682)\n\tat 
javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2121)\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.utils.Custom.getEncryptionKey(Custom.java:312)\n\tat 
com.sample.example.sdk.manager.utils.Custom.\u003cinit\u003e(Custom.java:108)\n\t
... 15 more\nCaused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException\n\tat 
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:519)\n\tat 
android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineUnwrap(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:680)\n\t... 18 more\n
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error\n\tat 
android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1137)\n\tat android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOp
```